# How to get count from repeater inside repeater in protractor?

Tags: protractor

I want to count the repeater that is nested into another repeater in protractor

```
var t2 = element.all(by.css('.footable.table.table-stripped.default.footable-loaded > tbody tr')).each(function(element, index){
        element.all(by.repeater("el in punchApproval| filter : filterEmpSearch | orderBy:'Emp_Code' track by $index ")).each(function(element, text){
            element.all(by.repeater("yl in el.PunchReq_sub")).count().then(function(cnt){
         console.log("Count rw:" +index +"rw desc"+text+"count"+cnt) ;
            });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the list identified by the repeater attribute.It must have a unique name then
print it using console.log(list) .where list contains the elements in the repeater you're having .

let list = element.all(by.repeater('.items li'));